# RPostgreSQL error relation"tablename" does not exist

Tags: r, postgresql

I am newbie trying to understand how R and PostgreSQL can talk to each other. I have used R lately only for data analysis but now, I am trying to import directly from a database. I have installed RPostgreSQL and have connected to my database, I can see all the tables but I cannot edit them. I would like get some data out of them but when I run the

the following code:

```
>query<-"SELECT * FROM Events"
> rs <- dbSendQuery(con,query)
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Events
```

My other table names are not great either. 
"Alarm_Reports"  ,"Configuration","Event_Details","Events"

Is there something basic about addressing the tables that I am missing?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It looks like you're connecting to the wrong database.  `ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist` is an error message coming from PostgreSQL itself.

Comment: If your table is really called `Events` in uppercase, you need to quote protect its name: try `select * from "Events"`.  Better still, keep table names lowercase.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, but in the PostgreSQL,I am using your examples to understand,  rs <- dbSendQuery(con,"select * from TableName"), does a special code exist? to separate the "Events" from the "select * from Events"

Comment: I added an answer, maybe that will help you. *Unquoted* upper-case identifiers always become lowercase, quote-protected upper-case is used as upper-case.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the table names.

Comment: Using the following code, I can query the database query<- "SELECT * FROM \"Events\""
> rs <- dbSendQuery(con,query)
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  permission denied for relation Events
)
Now I get the error of permission denied

Comment: Which proves that the table was found, now you need to get yourself access to the database from a network socket --- that is a PostgreSQL admin topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, quotes may be needed.  Here is actual code from one of our unit tests files:

```
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "create table Foo1 (f1 int)")
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "create table \"Foo2\" (f1 int)")

cat("Test should create foo1 and Foo2 tables\n")
## res <- dbGetQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables",
##                              "WHERE table_schema = 'public'")
## print res

if (dbExistsTable(con, "Foo1")) {
    cat("FAIL - Foo1 Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("Pass - Foo1 Table does not exist.\n")
}

if (dbExistsTable(con, "foo1")) {
    cat("Pass - foo1 Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("FAIL - foo1 Table does not exist.\n")
}

if (dbExistsTable(con, "Foo2")) {
    cat("Pass - Foo2 Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("FAIL - Foo2 Table does not exist.\n")
}

if (dbExistsTable(con, "foo2")) {
    cat("FAIL - foo2 Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("Pass - foo2 Table does not exist.\n")
}

if (dbExistsTable(con, "\"Foo2\"")) {
    cat("FAIL - \"Foo2\" Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("Pass - \"Foo2\" Table does not exist.\n")
}

if (dbExistsTable(con, "\"foo2\"")) {
    cat("FAIL - \"foo2\" Table exists.\n")
}
else {
    cat("Pass - \"foo2\" Table does not exist.\n")
}

res <- dbGetQuery(con, "drop table Foo1")
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "drop table \"Foo2\"")
```

Comment: That's from the `tests/` directory, using the much older-school `tests/foo.R` vs `tests/foo.Rout.save` comparison. I use `RUnit` a lot in other packages.